# How to "return false" and send a message with it?

Tags: php, exception

Is there any option in PHP to "return false" from a function and send a corresponding message with that (as in what went wrong)?

Is throwing an exception the best way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Validation function to return true|false, AND a message if false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765057/php-validation-function-to-return-truefalse-and-a-message-if-false)

Answer (score 3):

throwing an exception is always good but it is not literally equal to `return false`
but if you logic can sustain an exception, it's okay to throw it. May be of some distinct type, not general `Exception` though

Comment: How about a general exception with a specific code to track the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, use exceptions, if you catch an exception you can set the var to false as well as receive an error message.

```
function foo($a = null) {
     if(!$a) {
         throw new Exception('$a must be defined');
     }
}

try {
    $var = foo();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $var = false;
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This way you can do whatever you like when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to return `true` or `false` on success or failure and return your variable in a parameter passed by reference.

I.e. change:

```
function foo()
{
   return true;
}
```

to

```
function foo(&$ret)
{
   if ( $something_went_wrong)
      return false;
   $ret = true;
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bla(){
   return false;
}
if(bla() === false){
    echo "Failed";
}
```

But I believe exceptions are better.